# Организация обмена клиент - сервер

Tags: delphi, сеть

Есть сервер с белым ip. К нему через интернет будут подключаться клиенты. После подключения клиента создается слушающий поток для этого клиента и ожидает команд от клиента. Как сделать так чтобы сервер мог передать любую команду клиенту если учитывать, что поток на ожидании. Можно ли в другом потоке отправить через клиентский сокет на сервере или создать подключение к клиенту как к серверу?

1. Протокол TCP
2. TSocket из модуля WinSock
3. Одновременно 20 - 30 клиентов
4. Среда разработки Delphi XE 3

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, включив информацию о: 1. Протокол взаимодействия (TCP/UDP/HTTP/etc) 2. Используемые (или планируемые к использованию) компоненты. 3. Предполагаемая нагрузка на сервер (количество одновременных подключений).

Comment: Еще уточняющий вопрос: используется TSocket, т.е. работа ведется на чистом WinAPI. Насколько критичен именно такой подход? Не лучше ли задействовать хотя бы TClient/TServerSocket? Это я к чему - работа с потоковым протоколом TCP на чистом WinAPI - тяжелая вещь, нужно учитывать разбиение/склейку пакетов, алгоритм Нагла, которые очень сильно проявятся при работе через интернет. Плюс - 30 потоков - не очень хорошая идея. Есть маленькая надстройка над TClient/TServerSocket, если работа с WinAPI не обязательна - могу попробовать выложить как вариант решения.

Comment: да, пожалуйста выложите. будет очень даже

Comment: Увы - мой код не вмещается в отведенное для ответа количество символов, а вложения вроде как не допускаются... Посему - пока могу дать только ссылку (архив сразу с примером и сами модули снабжены очень подробными комментариями). http://forum.vingrad.ru/index.php?showtopic=379887&view=findpost&p=2623834

Comment: Выходит , что не нужно создавать для обслуживания каждого клиентского сокета  на сервере отдельный поток?

Comment: Не нужно. Каждый поток - это доп. нагрузка на сервер. При необходимости выполнения тяжелой работы на сервере обычно организуют пул потоков, каждый из которых при необходимости подхватывает работу с определенным соединением. Отдельный поток на каждое подключение - слишком расточительно.

Comment: спасибо.  смотрю ваш код. у меня вылетает ошибка `if FPacketHeader.DataSize > MAX_PACKET_SIZE then
        raise EInOutError.Create('Размер пакета превышает допустимый');` как то некорректно копируется скорее всего. пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38367/discussion-between-kami-and-gregor).